# How to implement "Does not Contain" or Negative Filter in Requestly

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extensions, redirection, web-development, requestly

I am using [Requestly Chrome & Firefox extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) to setup Redirects. I have a use case in which I want to switch the host from say - www.a.com to www.b.com except when www.a.com has a specific path (e.g. www.a.com/do_not_switch)

I know Requestly supports [Regex and WildCard matches](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/06/15/requestly-rule-operators/) but I do not see an option to provide a negative filter - something like Does not Contain.

Need help in achieving this use case. Here's the example

**Redirect** https://gsd.zgjx.zwa.com/* --> https://asc.zxc.com/*

**except** https://gsd.zgjx.zwa.com/gsd/translation/...

PS: Posting this question on behalf of a user as the solution to this problem is generic and will be applicable/helpful to other users in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requestly does not support negative filter (e.g. Does Not Contain) but you can use a simple trick to solve this use case.

### Summary

I have solved and created the rule for you. Please follow these steps

1. Install [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa)
2. Open https://app.requestly.in/rules/#sharedList/1566298072114-Negative-Filter-example-support-request
3. Click `Import List` button on top right

### Details

#### Step 1 - Change hostname to something else when URL matches your exception condition

```
URL Matches (WildCard) https://gsd.zgjx.zwa.com/gsd/translation/*
Destination https://www.dummyhost.com/gsd/translation/$1
```

#### Step 2 - Define a generic pair to setup Redirection

In the next pair, add the Redirection Logic generically for all the paths. Please note that it won't apply to your exception path because the hostname has already been changed in the first pair.

```
URL Matches (WildCard) https://gsd.zgjx.zwa.com/*
Destination https://asc.zxc.com/$1
```

#### Step 3 - Revert the dummy hostname to the original

```
URL Matches (Wildcard) https://www.dummyhost.com/gsd/translation/*
https://gsd.zgjx.zwa.com/gsd/translation/$1
```

#### Here's a screenshot to help you with the visual

[image]

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, we use the RegEx negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)`. Only one pair is needed.

[I've already created the rule.](https://app.requestly.io/rules/#sharedList/1704869495297) To use it, just open the link, click the `Import to My Rules` button on the top right, and test it.

Alternatively, you can create the rule manually:

1. Create a new rule.
2. In the `If request` section, choose `Matches (RegEx)` in the operator dropdown menu.
3. Paste this RegEx code into the field:

   ```
   /^https:\/\/gsd\.zgjx\.zwa\.com(?!\/gsd\/translation)/
   ```

   The most important part is that list bit `\.com(?!\/gsd\/translation)`. It's saying that if `.com` is **not** followed by `/gsd/translation`, then the URL matches.

   [Here's a step-by-step explanation of the RegEx.](https://regex101.com/r/6IfEoi/1)
4. In the `Redirects to` section, paste this into its field.

   ```
   https://asc.zxc.com/
   ```
5. Your rule should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvaDv.png).
6. Save and test your rule.

Comment: Thanks Zach for sharing this! This is excellent. Albeit it may be slightly overwhelming for people to understand and define the right regex with negative lookahead.